# D3 plotting longitude/latitude of null projection

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, geo

The d3.geo.path has a null projection because the TopoJSON is already projected, so it can be displayed as-is. I'm trying to plot data in the form of [longitude, latitude] on a map.

Below is what my code basically looks like:

```
var width, height, path, svg;

width = 960;
height = 600;
path = d3.geo.path().projection(null);
svg = d3.select('.viz').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

d3.json("counties.json", function(error, us) {
    svg.append('path')
        .datum(topojson.mesh(us))
        .attr('d', path);
});

svg.selectAll('.pin')
    .data(ds) // i.e. ds = {[12.521, 15.312], [616.122,-31.160]}
    .enter().append('circle', '.pin')
    .attr('r', 3)
    .attr('transform', function (d) {
        return 'translate(' + path([
            d.longitude,
            d.latitude
        ]) + ')';
    });
```

I debugged through this, and I do get the data fine. But, I am getting an error that "path([d.longitude, d.latitude])" is undefined. "d" exists with longitude and latitude values. "path" also exists. I think it's because the projection is null.

What can I do to make this work?

**------- EDIT -------** 
I followed the recommendation by Ben Lyall to remove the use of "path" in the selectAll statement as well as moving the selectAll statement inside the .json(). I also noticed I put in an incorrect example for ds, so I modified the comment. Here is my updated code.

This displays the map fine with no console errors, but I still don't see any circles in the map itself.

```
var width, height, path, svg;

width = 960;
height = 600;
path = d3.geo.path().projection(null);
svg = d3.select('.viz').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

d3.json("counties.json", function(error, us) {
    svg.append('path')
        .datum(topojson.mesh(us))
        .attr('d', path);

    svg.selectAll('.pin')
        .data(ds) // i.e. ds = [{longitude: 12.521, latitude: 15.312}, {longitude: 616.122, latitude: -31.160}]
        .enter().append('circle', '.pin')
        .attr('r', 3)
        .attr('transform', function (d) {
            return 'translate(' +
                d.longitude + ',' + d.latitude +
            ')';
        });
});
```

**------- EDIT -------** 
The solution was a combination of Ben Lyall's proposed solution as well as taking into account the projection already done on the map for the `.pin`s. Since the projection in code is null, I had to create a new one that matches the projection for the map and then use that when performing the transform on the `.pin`'s.

**Below is the solution:**

```
var width, height, path, projection, svg;

width = 960;
height = 600;
path = d3.geo.path().projection(null);
projection = d3.geo.albersUsa().scale(1280).translate([width/2, height/2]);
svg = d3.select('.viz').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

d3.json("counties.json", function(error, us) {
    svg.append('path')
        .datum(topojson.mesh(us))
        .attr('d', path);

    svg.selectAll('.pin')
        .data(ds)
        .enter().append('circle', '.pin')
        .attr('r', 3)
        .attr('transform', function (d) {
            return 'translate(' +
                projection([d.longitude, d.latitude]) +
            ')';
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're positioning your `.pin` elements, why are you using `path` in your `translate`?  You don't want to create a path, and the `d.latitude` and `d.longitude` values should already be in pixel co-ordinates, since they're projected already, so you should be able to use them directly.

Note: you probably also want that part of your code inside the `d3.json` handler, rather than outside, since it'll run asynchronously before your data is set to anything (this is probably the actual issue with your code, rather than using `path` incorrectly).

It's a little hard to confirm without an example to fork, but try this:

```
var width, height, path, svg;

width = 960;
height = 600;
path = d3.geo.path().projection(null);
svg = d3.select('.viz').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

d3.json("counties.json", function(error, us) {
    svg.append('path')
        .datum(topojson.mesh(us))
        .attr('d', path);

    svg.selectAll('.pin')
        .data(ds) // i.e. ds = {[12.521, 15.312], [616.122, -31.160]}
        .enter().append('circle', '.pin')
        .attr('r', 3)
        .attr('transform', function (d) { 
            return 'translate(' + d.longitude + "," + d.latitude + ')';
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ben for this! I updated my code. This time I don't get console errors, but I still don't see any pins in the map. I updated my original post.

Comment: You're going to have to show us an example in that case, without seeing what your `ds` values are it's going to be difficult to diagnose.

Comment: I found out that the issue was not the data but the projection for the .pin's. The .pin's need to use the same projection that was already done for the map. I have posted the solution. Thanks.

Comment: This is precisely why I said you needed to include more information in your question, in particular the values in your `ds` array.  Not sure how you would expect anyone to answer this question without access to those values.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your feedback. However, I am confused at your comment. I believe I provided more than enough information, but I will be more careful next time. I provided example values. The fact is, you don't need to know the actual values in ds to know what was wrong with the code that I had, given that I am using a null projection because the topojson is already projected. The issue was that the .pin's didn't know what projection to use, not the data. This can be seen in my code which I figured out without debugging through the data. Thanks Ben for the help you provided.

Comment: Only you knew that the values in your `ds` array weren't already projected.  Since you tried to apply the `null` projection to them in your first code extract, I figured that they were also already projected and you were just having issues displaying the `circle` elements.  I actually stated that in the first paragraph of my answer, but since you didn't comment on that it seemed likely that my assumption was correct.  With the `ds` array it would have been possible to determine the source of the problem.

Comment: I apologize. I may not have been so clear. I will not mark my answer as correct if you feel that it shouldn't be the solution (it got a minus after all from you I imagine). I merely wanted to help those who are having similar issues. I can remove this question altogether if you like or just leave this be with no marked answer. It doesn't matter for me. Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Technically, neither my nor your answer actually solves the issue by itself, the `projection` was not the only problem with your example code, it also had the `path` applied to it, which is not correct either.  So a combination of the two answers is actually correct.  It's probably worth updating your answer to include that as well, but your updated question also has the all the information to answer it now, so I'll leave it up to you as to what is the best course of action.

Comment: I think it'd be best to mark your solution as correct. I did come to the correct solution by building it on top of the changes you proposed. Thanks Ben. I posted the code of the solution I previously posted in the bottom of the question.